# Android Emulator - How to Run Chrome App After Upgrade

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am trying to upgrade the Chrome app on the Pixel 4 emulator but am unable to run it after upgrade.

To upgrade the version of Chrome to the latest, I run:

```
adb -s install -r com.android.chrome_89.0.4389.105-438910521_minAPI24\(x86\)\(nodpi\)_apkmirror.com.apk
```

It gives me this:

```
Performing Streamed Install

Success
```

However, on the emulator it removed the Chrome app icons so how can I launch the chrome app after upgrade?  It DOES appear in Settings > Apps and the version is upgraded to the version from the apk file I gave.

If I try running it via the following adb command:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```

I get:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main } Error type 3 Error: Activity class {com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main} does not exist.
```

Is there a way to get the Chrome App Icons to show after upgrade or is there another adb command I can use?

Answer (score 1):

We determined that using this apk instead works:
https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-89-0-4389-105-release/google-chrome-fast-secure-89-0-4389-105-16-android-apk-download/download/?forcebaseapk